# How to convert Cloudera Hadoop "vbox" VMDK to VirtualBox VDI

Tags: hadoop, vmware, virtualbox, cloudera

Hi guys : I am trying to run the Cloudera Hadoop VM in Virtual box.

- First, I noted that the download is a .vmdk file. Of course, this suffix is for VMWare, so that was a bit odd.
- Luckily, I found a tutorial on how to convert the cloudera vmdk into a virtual box file here : http://www.ubuntugeek.com/howto-convert-vmware-image-to-virtualbox-image.html.  However, when I tried to convert the vmdk file to a virtual box file by using  convertdd, and ultimately got a message that "Failed to write to disk image "cdh.vdi" VERR_DISK_FULL"
- So my question is , how do you run the Cloudera Hadoop VM in vbox ?  I found a site http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=108313592002 here, but it does not appear to work (this site suggests loading the VMDK image as a new hard disk, but "new" hard disks are not enabled in my fresh virtual box install). I only get "remove" and "refresh" options in my VBox disk manager.

OUTPUT FROM VBOX CONVERTING TO CDH

~/Development$ VBoxManage convertdd /tmp/vh.bin cdh.vdi
Converting from raw image file="/tmp/vh.bin" to file="cdh.vdi"...
Creating dynamic image with size 5475663872 bytes (5222MB)...
VBoxManage: error: Failed to write to disk image "cdh.vdi": VERR_DISK_FULL
 :~/Development$ ls

Answer (score 4):

1. VBox supports VMDK since v2.0 AFAIR.
2. VBox UI of Virtual Media Manager changed in 4.0 version, so there is no direct option of adding hard disk in Virtual Media Manager (there used to be one -- strange decision in my opinion).

   Although, you can create a new virtual machine in Virtualbox, and in the stage of choosing disk, choose existing one (VMDK) so you don't need to convert VMDK to VDI (there is a dropdown, but besides, also a button to choose a hard disk file not listed yet in Virtual Media Manager.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a guide from Cloudera themselves: http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2009/07/cloudera-training-vm-virtualbox/

Answer (score 1):

I created a new VM using Red Hat 64b. Chose existing drive and opened the vmdk file. Gave it 2G Ram and it started up fine.